# How to add file browser to music player app?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio

I have developed a music player app using Android studio but it lacks a functionality, file browser. I don't know how to implement it. Can anyone help me to implement it? Or is there any github repository which help to implement the feature?

Comment: Do you mean you want to be able to select a media file to play from file?

Comment: Do you want the full code for a file browser? search google, You will get a lot of examples for a file browser

Answer (score 0):

I use https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser in my media app. Easy to use and works excellent.

Answer (score 0):

public void onClick(View v) {

```
            final Uri currentTone =
                    RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(ringtone1.this,
                            RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
            Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Tone");
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, currentTone);
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, false);
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 999);
        }
    });
```